# Message : Web Project URL for deployment of Web Service not set in Eclipse ?

Tags: eclipse, web-services, wsdl, apache-axis

I was trying to develop a small web service using eclipse and deploying it to glassfish.

So, I've created a new Dynamic Web Project and a new top down web service (using the wizard).

When I try to publish the web service, i've got this error :

```
"IWAB0054E Web project URL for deployment of Web service is not set in AxisDeployCommand"
```

I can't see any error in the errorLog and don't know where to configure this "Web Project URL". Do you have any clue ?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the http binding (I was using HTTP protocol instead of SOAP) in my wsdl were problematic. I don't know exactly why.

Creating a new WSDL file with SOAP does work.

Comment: Can you please explain how you resolved this issue? I am facing similar problem. Detail explanation will help.